# How long will an item stay unclaimed in Treasure Hunter?

Tags: runescape

Yesterday, I used one of my Treasure Hunter keys and was awarded a Lucky Armadyl Chestplate. However, since there is a TH promotion going on that rewards "oddments" as well, all items will be converted to oddments instead of coins if you choose that option. I have no need for the chestplate and would like to convert it to coins, but since the promotion is going on, I can't convert it to coins until the promotion is over, (I believe its over on August 7th).

**My question is**: How long can I leave the chestplate unclaimed before it will disappear? Will it stay in there indefinitely until I decide to do something with it? Or will it go away when Treasure Hunter resets at reset time?

Comment: I want to say the answer is indefinite unless they change treasure hunter to something else.  According to the Wiki page, when they transferred from the Squeal of Fortune to Treasure Hunter, and unclaimed items were converted into keys.  So unless this happens, I would think your chestplate would still be there.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Would be really dumb of Jagex to make people lose unclaimed items, especially ones of such a high convert value.

Comment: Just a quick thing as well - If you win an item as part of a promotion but you don't claim it, the item can still be claimed even after the promotion (Happened to me with a [Pumpkin amulet](http://runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Pumpkin_amulet))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I waited until reset happened tonight and then checked Treasure Hunter to see if the chestplate was still there... and it was! So it looks like items will stay unclaimed until you claim them regardless of game reset. However, this does make Treasure Hunter unplayable until claimed.